# Memcache alternatives, more control

Tags: php, caching, memcached

My new PHP application could be sped up with some caching of MySQL results.
I have limited experience with memcached, but I don't think it can do what I require.

As I am working on a multi-user application I would like to be able to delete several stored values at once without removing *everything*.

So I might store:

```
account_1.value_a = foo
account_1.value_b = bar
account_2.value_a = dog
account_2.value_b = cat
```

Is there a caching system that would allow me to delete based on a wildcard (or similar method) such as "delete account_1.*" leaving me with:

```
account_1.value_a = <unset>
account_1.value_b = <unset>
account_2.value_a = dog
account_2.value_b = cat
```

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, but you can fake it by using version numbers in your keys.

For example, if you use keys like this:

```
{entitykey}.{version}.{fieldname}
```

So now your `account_1` object keys would be:

```
account_1.1.value_a
account_1.1.value_b
```

When you want to remove `account_1` from the cache, just increment the version number for that object.  Now your keys will be:

```
account_1.2.value_a
account_1.2.value_b
```

You don't even need to delete the original cached values - they will fall out of the cache automatically since you'll no longer be using them.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [memcache and wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595904/memcache-and-wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

Open source module to get tags for keys in memcache, and other:
http://github.com/jamm/memory/

Answer (score 0):

Scache (http://scache.nanona.fi) has nested keyspaces so you could store data on subkeys and expire parent when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached delete by tag can be done like this;

Searching and deleting 100,000 keys is quite fast, but performance should be monitored in much larger caches.

> **Before Php 8.0**

```
$tag = "account_1";
$cached_keys = $this->memcached->getAllKeys();

foreach($cached_keys as $key){
    if(substr($key, 0, strlen($tag)) === $tag){
        $this->memcached->delete($key);
    }
}
```

> **Php 8.0 >**

```
$tag = "account_1";
$cached_keys = $this->memcached->getAllKeys();

foreach($cached_keys as $key){
    if (str_starts_with($key, $tag)) {
        $this->memcached->delete($key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but for anyone who have same issue, you can use [APCu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php), which is so fast and lightweight. It can do what OP asked (by using regex).

Example:

```php
apcu_store('user1Address', "some data");
apcu_store('user1Name' , "some other data");
apcu_store('user2Name' , "some other data again");;

echo "All cached data:<br>";
foreach (new APCUIterator('/^.*/') as $item) {
    echo $item['key'] . " -> " . $item['value'] . "<br>";
}


//Delete all cache that thair key start with 'user1'
foreach (new APCUIterator('/^user1.*/') as $item) {
    apcu_delete($item['key']);
}

echo "All cached data after delete:<br>";
foreach (new APCUIterator('/^.*/') as $item) {
    echo $item['key'] . " -> " . $item['value'] . "<br>";
}
```

And the output would be:

```
All cached data:
user1Name -> some other data
user1Address -> some data
user2Name -> some other data again
All cached data after delete:
user2Name -> some other data again
```

*Note that `APCu` is not installed by default*